# Can't have a regular property and computed property keys in the same interface

Tags: typescript

TypeScript version: 3.6.4

In my state, I want to have both a computed property and a regular property key inside an interface but TypeScript is having trouble parsing that. Before creating a GitHub issue on the repository, I just want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong and wasting the devs' time.

```
type Stat = 'hp' | 'attack' | 'defense' | 'speed';

interface State {
    [x in Stat]: number;
    type: string
}
```

I thought that would work but then TypeScript highlights `type` and says `'}' expected. ts(1005)`. If I put `type` at the top, it highlights `[x in Stat]` and says `A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'. ts(2464)` & `'Stat' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`. If i comment out one of the 2 lines, TypeScript is totally okay with it.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
type Stat = 'hp' | 'attack' | 'defense' | 'speed';

type State = Record <Stat, number> & {
  type: string;
}

const s: State = {
  hp: 100,
  attack: 12,
  defense: 12,
  speed: 3,
  type: "myType"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a better understanding of what you are working on, my proposal may be off target.

You can probably work out something from mapped types and intersection:

```js
/** Refefernce interface */
interface IStat {
  attack: unknown;
  defense: unknown;
  hp: unknown;
  speed: unknown;
}

/** (optional) `keyof` reference interface */
type Stat = keyof IStat

/** Mapped IStat properties intersected with `type` */
type State = {
  [K in keyof IStat]?: number; // change `number` with IStat[K] if you want the types from IStat;
} & { type: string; };
```

Here is a [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/PQKhAICUFMDM+gJwHYGNrgJbIC5NgIbrgjACwAUNnoocQJIDKOBO4A3peOKy6gNYAucAFdk-ZAHsA7sgDcXcABMEyAM7RhYiTPmKAFgAct4qbIUVuaw9GhKTO85QC+lSqAgAKSYZyZJyAQANgCU4AAG-NAAnpKw4eCICEloGNT4RBiklDjRNuDMrOAAvOBRsbDgTCw4bhQe4ACyBIY2SlWFbIaIPkh+0GpYuEgaqHjt0pg4+hG5NgnZFHMYnRilnJbgANoA0kNlMXEdNQC6APzCyCIAtgBGSHLgwMDgqPoEyADmGOFXd0gJSbTY6sXYnLCVWIicDSD5saYYZaDWA9a4gnAWZzgABkHHAy2EahwiGwn0ezgsQA) for you to experiment further this approach.